# How to avoid step into built in types in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

For example, for this typical case below, how to avoid entering built-in c++ container's implementation in gdb?

```
addInfo(string key, vector<pair<string,double> > &weights)
```

At this line if I use 'step' to try to enter the function, the debugger first goes into stl containers like below:

```
std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::operator[] (this=0x7fffffffdc10, __n=5) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:770
770       operator[](size_type __n)
(gdb) 
771       { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
(gdb)
```

If I don't have a breakpoint inside the function, is there a way to avoid entering the  built-in types by gdb?